# PHP unset object in foreach loop, $key is name instead of iteration number

Tags: php, object, foreach, simplexml

I need to unset one of the payments objects but with the code I'm using, I can't get it to work right because `$k` is not the actual iteration key, it is the name of the object `Payment`.

How do I get the numerical key of the iteration?

```
    // var_dump of object
    object(add_nodes)#14 (1) {
      ["Payments"]=>
      object(add_nodes)#15 (1) {
        ["Payment"]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          object(add_nodes)#18 (5) {
            ["PaymentStatus"]=>
            string(9) "Succeeded"
            ["Payer"]=>
            string(10) "podve"
            ["Payee"]=>
            string(11) "PitneyBowes"
            ["PaymentTime"]=>
            string(24) "2018-11-09T09:18:27.000Z"
            ["PaymentAmount"]=>
            string(5) "47.73"
          }
          [1]=>
          object(add_nodes)#19 (7) {
            ["PaymentStatus"]=>
            string(9) "Succeeded"
            ["Payer"]=>
            string(10) "podve"
            ["Payee"]=>
            string(14) "jannesmith"
            ["PaymentTime"]=>
            string(24) "2018-11-09T09:18:27.000Z"
            ["PaymentAmount"]=>
            string(6) "102.99"
            ["ReferenceID"]=>
            string(17) "09273450972340987534"
            ["FeeOrCreditAmount"]=>
            string(4) "4.21"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

The code:

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($response, 'add_nodes');       
    $payments = $obj->Payments;
    if(count($payments->Payment) > 1 ) {

        foreach($payments->Payment as $k => $v) {
            echo $k; // This = Payment, not 0 or 1
            if($v->Payee != 'jannesmith') {
                unset($payments->Payment[$k]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not set it and increment it yourself? `$i = 0; foreach(...) { ... $i++; }`?

Comment: ya I thought about that, but I want to first figure out why $k is not the numerical key and how to get it properly.

Comment: Pass it by reference to the loop: `foreach($payments->Payment as &$v) if ($v->Payee !== "janeesmith") unset $v;` Not sure if this will work I don't use SimpleXML.

Comment: This should work the way you expect, so I'm puzzled as well. If you utout `$v->Payee`, does it return the expected result?

Comment: Also, posting the XML would be more useful than a dump of a SimpleXML object.

Comment: I already tried reference with the `&` and it didn't work.

Comment: And yes `$v->Payee` gives expected result. `$k` is not the numerical key though. So, I'm trying to figure out how to get the numerical key of the iteration without doing my own `$i = 0 $i++` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, I've always been partial to DomDocument and XPath, as it's exactly the same as doing DOM traversal and manipulation in JavaScript, Swift, etc. You don't need to learn all the tricky intricacies of a language-specific implementation like SimpleXML.

```
$response = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocRoot>
<Payments>
    <Payment>
        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
        <Payer>podve</Payer>
        <Payee>Pitney Bowes</Payee>
        <PaymentTime>2018-11-09T09:18:27.000Z</PaymentTime>
        <PaymentAmount>47.73</PaymentAmount>
    </Payment>
    <Payment>
        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
        <Payer>podve</Payer>
        <Payee>jannesmith</Payee>
        <PaymentTime>2018-11-09T09:18:27.000Z</PaymentTime>
        <PaymentAmount>102.99</PaymentAmount>
        <ReferenceID>09273450972340987534</ReferenceID>
        <FeeOrCreditAmount>4.21</FeeOrCreditAmount>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
</DocRoot>
XML;

$doc = new DomDocument;
$doc->loadXML($response);
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("/DocRoot/Payments/Payment[not(./Payee='jannesmith')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocRoot>
<Payments>

    <Payment>
        <PaymentStatus>Succeeded</PaymentStatus>
        <Payer>podve</Payer>
        <Payee>jannesmith</Payee>
        <PaymentTime>2018-11-09T09:18:27.000Z</PaymentTime>
        <PaymentAmount>102.99</PaymentAmount>
        <ReferenceID>09273450972340987534</ReferenceID>
        <FeeOrCreditAmount>4.21</FeeOrCreditAmount>
    </Payment>
</Payments>
</DocRoot>
```

Comment: SimpleXML seems to have a lot of fudges in it, DOMDocument is much more suited to when you need some proper XML hacking.